# can't ssh cascaded (second) router from wan

Tags: router, asuswrt-merlin

I've a simple 2 router network configuration:
1-st router is DHCP/WAN/NAT and
2-nd router is connected to the 1-st (cascaded) configured as AP (AP mode)

I can access both routers GUI, there is internet from/on both routers, **but I can't ssh to the 2-nd router FROM WAN** (there is a setting to LAN):
[image]
DHCP/WAN/NAT - all disabled on 2-nd router.

1-st router is a simple cable modem-router box, 2-nd router runs asus merlin

Any ideas how to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, all what was needed, is to add port forward for port 22 (ssh port) on 1-st (main) router, like this:
[image]